# How to keep alive a subprocess in jupyter

Tags: python, subprocess, google-earth-engine

I have a jupyter notebook that is doing a geospatial analysis using Google Earth Engine and then calling a script with the *%run* command. In that script, after send the tasks to download from GEE I have a subprocess that each 60 seconds is checking whether a tasks is done or not (to start the connection with GDrive and then download the image). What I want to know is why –after I close the jupyter notebook–, and the PID of the exporting process is still running, seems like the process has ended, without finished the 'while loop' which could take several hours.

```
def export_images(tasks_file_name, out_path):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['python3',  '/home/download.py',
                                tasks_file_name,
                                out_path
                            ],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                            universal_newlines=True)
    return process
```